# Java Graphics not painting on bottom and right side

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

Why does this not render the bottom and right sides. How do I fix it?
There is a small white area where nothing ever gets drawn? I'm sure there is a simple fix to this but I am too stupid.

I've got rid of anything that is not necessary, but there might still be some random useless code.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
    /**
     * Default serial version
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private static final int WIN_WIDTH = 760;
    private static final int WIN_HEIGHT = 480;

    private boolean running;
    private Thread thread;
    public Graphics g;
    public Graphics2D g2d;
    static final int UPDATE_RATE = 60;
    static final long UPDATE_PERIOD = 1000000000L / UPDATE_RATE;

    static public final int EONWIDTH = 24;
    static public final int EONHEIGHT = 24;

    /**
     * Contains a list of Eon instances by their instance ID.
     */

    ///////////////////////////////////CONSTRUCTER/////////////////////////////
    public Test()
    {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);       
    }

    /**
     * Main java runnable, required
     * @param args Unused, required by default
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test game = new Test();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("See guys, It's off centered... - 00.00.10");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.isFocusable();
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.g = game.getGraphics();

        game.start(game);
    }


    private void loopUpdate(Test game)
    {
            game.repaint();
    }

    boolean done = true;
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    { 
        System.out.print(g.getClipBounds().width + ", " + g.getClipBounds().height + "\n");
        super.paint(g);
        g.setClip(0,0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (done) 
        {
            done=false;

            try
            {

        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIN_WIDTH + 100, WIN_HEIGHT + 100);


        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g.dispose();
            done = true;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        loopUpdate(this);
    }
}
```

[image: This is the output]

Please. I know that pretty much everyone here knows how to fix this so please can someone just help me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod Sorry, will do

Comment: You don't have to shout; +1 for (near) [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming the size of the JPanel is exactly WIN_WIDTH and WIN_HEIGHT in size. Use `getBounds()` instead of your constants to get the actual realized size of your JPanel. The actual sizing is up to the discretion of the container's LayoutManager, so you can investigate different layout managers or absolute positioning if you absolutely require the exact dimensions you specified.